# Xls To Xlsx Converter need junit test class

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, junit4

I have written the java code for xls to xlsx converter, but i'm not good at writing the Junit test cases, so can you help me out how to write a test class for below code , thanks you.

```java
import java.io.File;

public class XlsToXlsxConverter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String basePath = "C:\\Users\\peramm1\\Documents\\IDX\\";

        File baseFile = new File(basePath);

        if (baseFile.isDirectory())
        {
            File[] filesList = baseFile.listFiles();

            try
            {
                for (File eachFile: filesList)
                {
                    String fileName = eachFile.getName();
                    if (fileName.endsWith(".xls"))
                    {
                        String[][] excelData = AdvancedApachePOI.readXls(eachFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        String writeFileName = eachFile.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll(".xls", ".xlsx");
                        AdvancedApachePOI.writeXlsx(excelData, writeFileName);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that you'll need to do some refactoring of it first before you can easily test it?

Comment: Yes, u mean i need to refactoring my code before write test class. how can i do that?